# Ansible: How can I replace values in nested dict?

Tags: ansible

How can I replace a value in nested dict with filters or jinja, I don't care the method as long as it works.

I have a service mapping defined in group_vars like so:

```
backend_services:
  svc1:
    env_vars:
      DB_DATABASE: svc1_db
      DB_HOST: "{{postgres_db.host}}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "{{postgres_db.password}}"
      DB_PORT: "{{postgres_db.port}}"
      DB_USER: "{{postgres_db.username}}"
      ENVIRONMENT: "{{environment_name}}"
      LOG_LEVEL: "{{default_log_level}}"
  svc2:
    env_vars:
      DB_DATABASE: svc2_db
      DB_HOST: "{{postgres_db.host}}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "{{postgres_db.password}}"
      DB_PORT: "{{postgres_db.port}}"
      DB_USER: "{{postgres_db.username}}"
      ENVIRONMENT: "{{environment_name}}"
      LOG_LEVEL: "{{default_log_level}}"

  svc3:
    env_vars:
      DB_DATABASE: svc3_db
      DB_HOST: "{{postgres_db.host}}"
      DB_PASSWORD: "{{postgres_db.password}}"
      DB_PORT: "{{postgres_db.port}}"
      DB_USER: "{{postgres_db.username}}"
      ENVIRONMENT: "{{environment_name}}"
      LOG_LEVEL: "{{default_log_level}}"
```

What I want to do is loop through this backend_services variable and replace all the DB_HOST values (which are presently hardcoded) with a value I have dynamically retrieved from the host environment.  For context, I am deploying into a cloud environment with a managed SQL instance that has been provisioned with Terraform.  I can get that managed sql host into a variable with set fact but then need to modify this mapping.

I've tried different looping methods, using combine, using nested loops with an include_tasks file, and using set_fact with jinja instead of filters.

What I **can** get to work is this:

```
set_fact:
  new_service: "{{ backend_services['svc1'] | combine({'env_vars': {'DB_HOST': 'foo'} }, recursive=True)}}"
```

However, I can't figure out how to *loop* that with all elements of backend_services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
set_fact:
  new_service: "{{ backend_services['svc1'] |
                   combine({'env_vars': {'DB_HOST': 'foo'} }, recursive=True)}}"
```

> Q: *"How to loop that with all elements of backend_services?"*

A: The tasks below do the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_services: "{{ backend_services.keys()|list }}"
    - set_fact:
        new_service: "{{ new_service|
                         default({})|
                         combine({item:
                                 {'env_vars':
                                  backend_services[item].env_vars|
                                  combine({'DB_HOST': 'foo'})}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_services }}"
```

Comment: This exactly solves the issue as I needed.  I had tried the double combine method before but couldn't get the syntax right.  I was even able to edit the original variable in place by replacing `new_service` with `backend_services` once I was able to validate the solution.